# Do we need to truncate test dataset for seq2seq LSTM?

Tags: natural-language, lstm, seq2seq

I am running a summarization model which uses a seq2seq biLSTM with an attention mechanism. It is a standard practice to truncate the input dataset during training to 400 - 500 tokens. My question is, during generation on the test dataset (or validation dataset), do I need to truncate that dataset as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the data at inference time should be pre-proprocessed the same way at the training time. Although the LSTMs in theory generalize for arbitrarily long output, in practice, they usually generalize only slightly beyond the scope of what was seen in the training data.

With summarization, the reason for truncating the input is, first of all, saving some memory, but it also based on assumption that the information that is important for the summary is mostly at the beginning of the text. Alternatively, you can do [extractive summarization firts and do the abstractive summary on top of that](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.03186).